# Django REST Framework's IsAdminUser doesn't prevent non-admin users

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to make one view admin-only.

I'm using a simple function-based view with the `@permission_classes` decorator. I want this to be available only to admin users.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser
from django.http import JsonResponse

@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def testing(request):
    return JsonResponse({"status": "ok", "user": request.user.username, "is_staff": request.user.is_staff})
```

However when I curl as an anonymous user the check clearly isn't applied:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/testing/
{"status": "ok", "user": "", "is_staff": false}
```

I would expect to be rejected if I wasn't logged in, or wasn't an admin user.

It looks like I'm using them correctly according to the [permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated) and [decorators](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api-policy-decorators) docs.

Comment: Try putting @api_view(['GET']) for example before @permission_classes (you should also import api_view)

Comment: Great, that does it, thanks very much. My API doesn't actually use the rest of the JRF, I only wanted it for the `BasicAuthentication,` so I didn't think to include the `@api_view`. Answer this, I'll tick it.

Comment: You are welcome! You could use some kind of custom middleware for that i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `@api_view(['GET'])` for example before `@permission_classes` (you should also import `api_view`) . An example from [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/):

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response

    @api_view(['GET'])
    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    def example_view(request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Comment: Thanks for actually posting your comment as an answer, as its the correct way.  To improve the answer, provide a code snippet with a full example, with proper formatting. Doing that will make it more helpful for others who, in the future, find this question.  Its ok to include an example from the official documenation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view), it doesn't have to be an original snippet